# polling between sockets and stdin in java

Tags: java, p2p, nio

I have to write a p2p program that has to act as both the client and the server. The program has to listen to both incoming connections(acts as server) and wait for the user input(acts as client). I am not sure what approach to take to do this.

I tried using NIO to list all the selectablechannels. I still am not able to figure out how to make the stdin as non-blocking!!

My program operates in console. So, no AWT allowed.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You need two threads at least: one to handle stdin, and one or more to handle the sockets, depending on whether you use non-blocking NIO or blocking I/O.